# PHP : Only display First 5 Lines of Variable

Tags: php

I've got a script to get emails, but I only want to output the first (most recent) 5 lines. Each email is displayed as

```
<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email Subject</span> </div>
```

so it's not simply ending in  or whatever, but it still does the same thing. I'm guessing the easiest way would be to only allow 5 s then cut the output, but how could I do this?

It's PHP, using this script, http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap

Comment: Can you describe in greater detail?  For example, you mention in comments that lines are separated by `div` tags, but you make no mention of this in your question.  It would be beneficial if you could use consistent terminology.  You have a script to get "emails", but you want 5 "lines", and "emails" are formatted with `div` tags.  Are emails and lines the same thing in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

**Solution1:**

In this piece of code: http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap ,add the second line of code:

```
 /* put the newest emails on top */
 rsort($emails);

 // add this line    
 $emails = array_slice($emails,0,5); // <---- this will consider only the first 5 elements.
```

**Solution2:**

In the foreach loop section, edit it like this:

```
/* for every email... */
$i = 0;  // <---- a counter variable
foreach($emails as $email_number) {
  $i++;  // <---- increment the counter
  if($i > 5) break; // <---- after 5 mails are accessed, exit the loop

  /* get information specific to this email */
  $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
  $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

  /* output the email header information */
  $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
  $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
  $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
  $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
  $output.= '</div>';

  /* output the email body */
  $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
}
```

---

**Original Solution**

Another way:

```
$content = "Hello. 
            This is some 
            kick butt 
            content!
            Even
            more
            lines
            ...";

$splitContent = implode("\n",array_slice(explode("\n",$content),0,5));  //split the lines, then select only the first 5 elements and now join it back it as a string
echo $splitContent;
```

Comment: It's not split via just a simple 'pressing enter' sort of thing. A new line is created when there is a </div>, so just like that doesn't work.

Comment: The script you are referring to, is a PHP script or JavaScript ? If it is a PHP script, then I think it would be better to edit that code and modify certain lines to make it display only the 5 mails that you needed. If you are saying it's a JS(dynamically polling the site for new mails, and displaying it in the page), then you should mention that in your question! I hope, you would edit your question to include these kind of details. :)

Comment: After this line: `rsort($emails);`, try this line: `$emails = array_slice($emails, 0, 5);` I haven't tested it. Hope it will work. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = "Hello. 
This is some 
kick butt 
content!
Even
more
lines
...";

$splitContent = split("\n", $content);
$line = 0;

while($line < 5) {
   echo $splitContent[$line];
   $line++;
}
```

Comment: It's not split via just a simple 'pressing enter' sort of thing. A new line is created when there is a </div>, so just like that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If it's like you say in your comment the DIV-tags which decides if there's a new line, you could do it with a regular expression like this:

```
$alldata = '';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 1 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 2 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 3 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 4 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 5 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 6 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 7 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 8 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 9 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 10 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 11 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 12 Subject</span> </div>';
$alldata .= '<div class="toggler unread"><span class="subject">Email 13 Subject</span> </div>';
// 13 times
$allarr[] = $alldata;

preg_match_all('#(<div class="toggler\ unread">(.|\r|\n)*?</div>)#i', $alldata, &$lines);

for ($n = 0; $n<5; $n++) { echo $lines[0][$n] . "\n"; }
```